# If-Else statement for parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I have a user table and an organization table. When you sign up for a user, the application also creates a new organization for you. I did this by putting this code in user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_organization
  belongs_to :organization

  private
  def create_organization
    self.organization = Organization.create :name => self.name
  end
end
```

But there will be some cases where parameters will be passed on through the URL, such as

```
http://localhost:3000/sign_up?organization_id=10
```

How do I create some sort of if-then statement so that if the `organization_id` parameter is present, the user model DOESN'T create a new organization.. But instead submits the existing `organization_id` parameter as the organization_id for the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple add check into your model,

```
  def create_organization
    organization = Organization.create :name => name unless organization_id.present?
  end
```

And in your controller simply set `organization_id` from `params`.

Comment: I put the unless argument, and `@user.organization_id = params[:organization_id]` in the `def create` part of the user controller. I no longer get an error but it still creates a new organization when a new user signs up..?

Comment: @cdotfeli just guessing but are you sure that organization_id is passed on to your `create` action ? It may be present when you navigate to `http://localhost:3000/sign_up?organization_id=10` but not when you submit the form...

Comment: @mark-guk NVM I got it. I had to put `@user.organization_id = params[:organization_id]` in the `def new` part of the user_controller, and put an `f.hidden_field :organization_id` in the user sign up view (wrapped inside `if params[:organization_id], else` code). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.organization = Organization.find(organization_id) rescue Organization.create :name => name
```

as `find` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` even if `params[:organization_id]` is not set.

Comment: Hmmm, putting this code just triggered a whole bunch of errors for me..? Do I need to put anything else in the controller?